# How to get characters at given positions from nvarchar value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I encountered with the following problem: I have a column of type nvarchar called "CaseFullNumber" which contains 14 digits. I need to take the 8th and 9th digits of that number and to perform other actions according to this if these two characters are "01" or "02" (they can be only "01" and "02"). I suppose there is a sql function which accomplishes this task but after research in google and stackoverflow I did not find any. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided which DBMS you're using.  (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) for this:

```
Select SubString(CaseFullNumber, 8, 2)
```

This pulls two characters starting at the 8th position in `CaseFullNumber`.

Comment: Some databases call this `substr()` but one or the other almost always works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this is exactly what i looked for!